# How do I write a function that returns the path from a node to another whose length is less than a given depth in OCaml?

Tags: graph, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to create a function that, given a graph, a starting node (start) an ending node (goal) and a maximum depth, returns the path from the start to the goal only if its depth is < than the given depth, if not it raises an error. I cant think of a way to do it in OCaml since i can't use an incrementing variable and compare it with the maximum depth. This is what i did so far:

```
let grafo = [(1,4); (1,2); (2,4); (3,2); (3,6);
             (4,4); (4,3); (4,5); (5,6); (6,3)];;

let rec vicini x = function
  [] -> []
| (a, b)::rest -> 
    if a = x then b :: vicini x rest
    else vicini x rest;;
    
exception NotFound;;
(* main function *)
let test_connessi g start goal depth =

  let rec from_node visited n = 
    if List.mem n visited then raise NotFound
    else if n = goal then [n]
    else n :: from_list (n :: visited) (vicini n g)
 
  and from_list visited = function
      [] -> raise NotFound
    | n::rest ->
        try from_node visited n 
        with NotFound -> from_list visited rest
  in 

  start :: from_list [] (vicini start g);;
```

How can I implement the depth thing?

Comment: First I'd start by cleaning up the grammar of the question to make it actually readable. When you're asking other people to donate their time in order to help you, it's a good idea to put in at least a minimum of effort in making it easy to help you. Then I'd ask myself, why can't I use an incrementing variable?

Comment: @glennsl whats wrong? also OCaml variables are immutable so i cant change their values...how do i do it?

Comment: What's wrong with your grammar? Capitalization, punctuation, sentence structure, obscure abbreviations etc. It seems mostly out of laziness though, which begs the question: If you put this little effort into the question, why would anyone put effort into giving you an answer?

Comment: It's also not strictly true that "variables" in OCaml are immutable. Firstly because they're not actually "variables", but more importantly there are ways of making mutable _references_. You don't actually need it though. All you need to do is bind a _new value_ to the _same name_. In a recursive function an argument is such a name, and calling the function with a value will bind the value to that name. Hence you can increment the value every time you call the function.

Comment: I was thinking I could do this faster by checking if the list length-1 is minor than the given depth. What do you think?

Comment: I don't see how that would be faster (if even correct). `List.length`is `O(n)`.

Comment: You state in your question that you cannot have an incrementing variable. In the sense of mutability, you sort of can in OCaml but it's generally not idiomatic. However, as you recursively iterate, you can increment by passing that state through a function parameter that gets incremented (or decremented as needed).

Comment: Consider finding the length of a list using tail recursion: `let rec len lst acc = match lst with [] -> acc | (_::xs) -> len xs (acc + 1)`. That `acc` value _increments_.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I implement the depth thing?

Exactly the same as you implemented the visited thing. Just add an extra parameter to your recursive function(s) and pass (depth+1) to the recursive calls. This is the functional style of incrementing a variable. You pass the new value of the variable to the recursive call.

Comment: This is definitely how it works, but i still can't make it work. If i add another parameter it just returns the exception NotFound